# How to get array identifier in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

how can I get the indentifier of an associative array (not Array object) in a for loop?

like so:

```
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<=myArray;i++)
{
   if(myArray.ident == 'title') alert('The title is ' + myArray['title']);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what your code is supposed to do, it seems that you make things more complicated than they are. I don't know whether you simplified your loop, but as it is now it is totally unnecessary, an `alert('The title is ' + myArray['title'])` would be sufficient (btw associative arrays are objects in JS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using a different `for()` loop, like this:

```
var myArray = { title: "my title", description: "my description" };
var i = 0;
for(var i in myArray) {
   //if(i == 'title') is the check here...
   alert('The '+ i + ' is ' + myArray[i]);
}​
```

Inside the loop, `i` is your identifier, e.g. `title` and `description`.  [You can play with this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/paL5f/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var i;
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";

for (i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++) {
  document.write(mycars[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ident** is the identifier in your case and `'title'` is its value ..

Please show us the actual array ..

normally to loop through an associative array you would do it like this..

```
for (key in myArray)
  {
    if (key == 'title')
      alert('The title is ' + myArray[key]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends somewhat on how you construct `myArray`, in general:

```
var myArray = {
   title: "foo",
   bleep: "bloop"
}

for (var k in myArray) {
   if (k == "title") 
      alert('The title is ' + myArray[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick Craver posted, loop through your data object (associative array), preferrably using the compact syntax, and check whether the property matches your string:

```
var myData = { /* properties: values */ } ;
var string = /* string to match */ ;

    for(var n in myData) {

            if(n == string) {
                // do something
            }

    }
```